# Login loop Ubuntu 18.04 after installing packages

Tags: login, mouse, touchpad, macbook

Yesterday I installed Linux Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time on my laptop.
I was just discovering and customizing my dock when I had the brilliant idea to simulate macbook touchpad.

I followed this link blindly :

https://int3ractive.com/2018/09/make-the-best-of-MacBook-touchpad-on-Ubuntu.html

First the mouse was not sensitive at all, and then I had the login loop problem.

Now I have no idea what to do since I'm an absolute newbie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I already tried this one, didn't work for me

Comment: It took you 1 minute to try 45 answers and dismiss all of them. If I had already tried 45 answers and all of them failed I would be so frustrated by this experience that I would have even included this information about what I tried in the original question.

Comment: you're right i'm looking right now

Comment: You mangled Xorg, which is the classic cause of a login loop, and that includes in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It *might* be enough, to get rid of the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mtrack.conf ` although some of the other commands listed in the webpage seem wrong to me.  Particularly the `adduser` command seems incorrectly structured.  The `dispad` utility would also be suspect.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I had to `sudo rm -r` this one

Comment: Which one was that?

Comment: You could likely could somehow reverse what you did, i.e, remove any created files, remove any startup apps, and make sure either xserver-xorg-input-libinput or xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 is installed. In Ubuntu it must be installed to log in. (- the former is on 18.04.1 image, later is on the 18.04.2 image). Far easier & quicker to just do a fresh install as your current is borked and 1 day old. In the future beware of blog instructions, especially if you see sudo gedit .. , the blog is either very old or the blogger is ill-informed

Comment: @doug Given the time invested already, you are probably correct that reinstalling might be easiest.

Comment: This is so much better than stackoverflow !

Comment: @CharlesGreen Why would the dispad utility would also be suspect ?

Comment: Given the oddities on the original webpage, and the fact that [dispad](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/dispad) has not seem any updates in the last 4 years, I would suspect that it may have trouble with some newer systems (such as Ubuntu 18.xx).  I may be wrong!  I did not download the source and check over the scripts, let alone look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by removing the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mtrack.conf` just as @CharlesGreen suggested.

Comment: You might want to run this command to see what, if anything, root owns in your home directory. `ls -lA -R  |grep "root root"`

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: I'm glad that worked!